# KVM host kernel configuration for best performance

Tags: kvm-virtualization, linux-kernel

I'm currently building a kernel for my server, which should serve for hosting virtual machines using KVM. There are a few kernel configuration options that are already described in the [KVM-Wiki](http://www.linux-kvm.org/page/Tuning_Kernel#Useful_options_for_the_kernel_of_the_host). The article left out some points which I'm wondering about, specifically:

- Should "Tickless System (Dynamic Ticks)" be set or not? It seems that Ingo Molnar apparently said that Dynamic Ticks would be helpful for a KVM host.
- What Preemption Model should the kernel use?
- What Timer Frequency value would you choose for a virtualization host kernel?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which OS distribution, version, hardware?

Comment: Latest Gentoo Linux, Kernel 3.3.8 with gentoo-Patchset (alias gentoo-sources), Hardware: Quad Core i7-3770 (Ivy Bridge)